# What makes multiplication a basic operation on natural numbers but exponentiation is not?

Tags: relations, natural-numbers, binary-operations

Dear StackExchange Math Community:
It has puzzled me for some time why multiplication is considered a basic arithmetic operation on natural numbers, but exponentiation is just viewed as a shorthand of repeated multiplication? My understanding is multiplication, like exponentiation, is simply a shorthand for repeated addition and not a distinct operation on natural numbers. Please explain. Thank you in advance.

Comment: When exponents are extended to rational or real numbers, they’re not just repeated multiplication

Comment: "*multiplication is simply a shorthand for repeated addition*"  How do you interpret $\sqrt{2}\times \pi$?  How many times do you "repeat" doing something here?  The moral of the story is that we may have *started* with defining multiplication *of naturals* as repeated addition and may have *started* with defining exponentiation *of naturals* as repeated multiplication, however once we relax the requirement that we are only talking about natural numbers and instead talk about integers or rationals or reals or even more exotic sets, such a **naive** interpretation is no longer sufficient.

Comment: In the end, even addition is not so "basic" when you have allowed yourself to talk about more exotic contexts or talked about the sets that you are familiar with but more formally.

Comment: Formally, as you'll see later on with *groups*, *rings* and family, multiplication - like addition - should be seen as a *function* $m:A\times A\to A$, with $A$ being your set - e.g. the naturals, or real numbers - and we formally interpret the more human-friendly notation $a\times b$ as $m(a,b)$. To define a sensible $m$ on real numbers, as JM says, you need more care (a lot more care) and the notion of repeated multiplication falls apart

Comment: With regards to multiplication being considered "easier" or "harder" than exponentiation and whether they should be classified as being different... *they aren't*.  They both qualify as being [elementary functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_function#:~:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20an%20elementary%20function,inverse%20functions).  If you have some source that says "multiplication is basic" while also saying "exponentiation is not" then that source is either wrong or not telling the whole story, that or has a very poor definition of what it means to be "basic"

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. In any case, even for rational, real, or imaginary numbers multiplication is formally called an operation but exponent is not, despite on the fact that exponent can also be represented as a function of two variables _m: A^A -> A_ and the expression $\left(\sqrt{2} \right)^{pi}$ cannot be strictly interpreted as a repeated multiplication.

Comment: "*multiplication is formally called an operation but exponent is not*"  That is false.

Comment: Agreed, my statement may be false, but I used the online Encyclopedia of Mathematics as the reference, and this encyclopedia defines **Multiplication** as an arithmetic operation [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Multiplication) and **Exponent** [link](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Exponent) just as an expression.

Comment: Since the linked pages of the Encyclopedia are the reason for your question, they should be explicitly cited in the question itself, not deep within the comment section. You can edit the question to fix that.

Comment: I think that even addition isn't a basic operation. The natural numbers are defined by Peano's axioms, and they only define a starting point and a successor for every natural number. That's it. However, with them, the properties of the successor, we can inductively define addition and multiplication. And, last but not least, as you see from my reasoning, that "basic" lies in the eye of the beholder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An *arithmetic operation* is a function from one or more (some say zero or more)
elements of a set $A$ to an element of the same set $A.$
The encyclopedia that inspired your question
[says this](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Algebraic_operation).
Whether one calls an arithmetic operation "basic" is (as far as I'm aware) simply a matter of opinion with some vague constraints, much like deciding whether a mathematics problem is "easy" or "difficult".

Whether or not you can use operation "$+$" to define "$\times$"
is irrelevant to whether "$\times$" is an operation.
Technically, it is sufficient that "$\times$" takes two numbers as input and produces a number as output.
But in practice, what makes some functions "operations" and other functions just "functions" is a matter of habit, convention, and convenience.

To be clear, however, **exponent** is just what we call the symbol $b$ in the expression $a^b,$ not the whole expression, as described in the Comment on the encyclopedia's page on "Exponent". That is, an **exponent** is just an expression that occurs within the operation called **exponentiation**, the same way **divisor** is an expression that occurs within the operation called **division**.

Why it says earlier on that page of the encyclopedia that **exponent** is the same as **exponential function** is a mystery to me; I have never seen anyone use the word "exponent" in that way.

Referring to the encyclopedia again,
[the page on the Ackermann function](https://encyclopediaofmath.org/wiki/Ackermann_function)
mentions "addition, multiplication, exponentiation, and all higher-order analogues of these operations", implying that exponentiation is considered an operation much like addition or multiplication.

For some reason, however, there is apparently no page in the encyclopedia named "Exponentiation".
I don't know why not, but you should keep in mind that no encyclopedia is really complete (or, for that matter, authoritative: if you need to establish a fact for a serious research paper, look elsewhere for a citation).